# ggplot2 following layer removing previous layer

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I add a layer to my ggplot graph, the previous layer settings disappear. I would like to keep the size of my chart points, but when I add another layer to change the background of my plot, the point sizes are removed.

Code for plot:

```
p <- ggplot(A,aes(zip, perc)) + geom_point() 
p <- p + labs(x = "Zip Code", y = "Percent Penetration") + 
          labs(title = "Zip Code Tier A") 
p + geom_point(aes(size = zgrp)) 
p + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "ivory"))
```

---

Data:

```
     zip    cgrp zgrp    perc  
 1: 12007    4   15 48.387097  
 2: 12008    4   25 41.666667  
 3: 12009    4  956 52.643172  
 4: 12010    4 1047 30.025810  
 5: 12018    4  859 49.113779  
 6: 12019    4  838 54.380273  
 7: 12020    4 1233 43.126967  
 8: 12022    4   37 34.579439  
 9: 12023    4  225 47.669492  
10: 12027    4  139 50.180505  
11: 12028    4   35 46.052632  
12: 12033    4 1062 48.559671  
13: 12041    4   47 42.342342  
14: 12046    4   55 43.650794  
15: 12047    4 1282 36.807350  
16: 12052    4  118 45.914397  
17: 12053    4  362 49.118046  
18: 12054    4 1818 59.743674  
19: 12055    4    2 50.000000  
20: 12056    4  117 45.703125  
21: 12057    4    9 19.565217  
22: 12059    4  198 55.153203  
23: 12061    4 1239 53.084833  
24: 12062    4  176 41.805226  
25: 12065    4 2829 48.483290  
26: 12066    4  101 46.976744  
27: 12067    4  156 45.086705  
28: 12074    4  105 47.085202  
29: 12077    4  644 57.295374  
30: 12083    4  144 43.243243  
31: 12084    4  328 43.328930  
32: 12090    4  121 41.296928  
33: 12094    4  136 38.746439  
34: 12110    4 1703 49.219653  
35: 12118    4  830 38.712687  
36: 12120    4   21 39.622642  
37: 12121    4  155 52.364865  
38: 12122    4   90 32.490975  
39: 12123    4  564 43.251534  
40: 12130    4   86 42.156863  
41: 12134    4   62 43.055556  
42: 12137    4   92 42.396313  
43: 12138    4  161 42.368421  
44: 12140    4  173 51.335312  
45: 12143    4  364 37.371663  
46: 12144    4 2172 38.903815  
47: 12147    4   32 48.484848  
48: 12148    4  279 61.184211  
49: 12150    4   38 40.000000  
50: 12151    4   47 52.808989  
51: 12153    4  115 63.535912  
52: 12154    4  161 43.869210  
53: 12156    4   97 48.743719  
54: 12158    4  621 44.230769  
55: 12159    4  861 63.636364  
56: 12168    4  118 51.754386  
57: 12169    4   19 35.185185  
58: 12180    4 3095 31.630046  
59: 12182    4  762 31.500620  
60: 12183    4  113 23.541667  
61: 12185    4  118 44.528302  
62: 12186    4  738 57.927786  
63: 12189    4 1122 32.682785  
64: 12193    4  148 40.326975  
65: 12196    4  370 53.237410  
66: 12198    4  801 48.871263  
67: 12202    4  301 10.591133  
68: 12203    4 2542 45.950832  
69: 12204    4  474 26.779661  
70: 12205    4 2483 42.928769  
71: 12206    4  543 14.056433  
72: 12207    4   41 10.049020  
73: 12208    4 1693 38.600091  
74: 12209    4  763 27.785870  
75: 12210    4  469 19.380165  
76: 12211    4 1028 57.174638  
77: 12302    4 1140 44.618395  
78: 12303    4 1850 41.931097  
79: 12304    4  938 26.370537  
80: 12305    4   98 12.911726  
81: 12306    4 1140 37.475345  
82: 12307    4   68  4.822695  
83: 12308    4  346 17.918177  
84: 12309    4 1776 51.270208  
85: 12469    4   16 37.209302
```

Comment: So your building this plot `p`, but the line where you set the size does not change `p`; so when you call the last line, `p` doesn't know anything about that size aesthetic.

Comment: I don't understand. The graph is saved to the object 'p' and I preface the size function by 'p +'. So how does it not know anything about the size aesthetic?

Comment: `p + geom_point(...)` does not save the object back into `p`. `p <- p + geom_point()` does save the object back into `p`.

Comment: To elaborate, either use `p + labs + geom_point + theme` or reassign `p <- p + ...` multiple times.

Comment: @SandyMuspratt Thank you! Was struggling with this for half an hour confused to as why it did not work.